# How to get back fo first element in list after reaching the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance:

If I am iterating through a Python list ['a','b','c'] how do I get back to element 'a' once I have reached 'c'?

Comment: Can you provide your code? It's unclear what your intention is exactly. Are you using a for loop? And do you want to end at the second pass of `'a'`? Or keep going?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean to do a loop like if your list was in circle, simply use the modulo operator :

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in range(n): # set n to desired value
    print(mylist[i % len(mylist)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "get back to element `'a'`" you mean to "cycle" back through the list, Then you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

data = ["a", "b", "c"]
times_to_iterate = 4

infinite_data = cycle(data)

for element in islice(infinite_data, len(data) * times_to_iterate):
    print(element)
```

I used `islice` as it's the same as the builtin `slice` but for iterators as `cycle` will iterate forever otherwise. This will iterate through `data` 4 times.